# Meaning of lost a dare

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Well, you know that Rob’s been wearing a long t-shirt recently. It’s because the other night he went out with some friends. Well, he **lost a dare** and now he’s got a tattoo of panda on a skateboard on his arm.

I can't understand what 'lost a dare' means here. What does it have to do with a tattoo of panda?

Answer (score 1):

A dare is a challenge, and sometimes a group of youths out drinking will challenge one of their number to do some silly thing. If that person tries to do that thing and fails, or refuses, they must pay a penalty, in this case, to have an embarrassing tattoo.

> Dare
> NOUN
> A challenge, especially to prove courage.
>
> ‘she ran across a main road for a dare’

[Dare (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dare)

> A middle-aged optometrist has been suspended after he failed to
> disclose his conviction for streaking more than 20 years ago, a
> misconduct tribunal ruled.
>
> In 1988 Jagdip Dhariwal stripped naked and ran down a street in
> Southampton as a result of a drunken dare with university friends
> during freshers' week.

[Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/05/07/optometrist-streaked-20-years-ago-drunken-dare-suspended-failing/)

Answer (score 0):

Person A: I can do anything you dare me to do!
Person B: Then, run butt naked in the street!

Person A takes of his clothes but just before she gets out of the door she gets cold feet.

Person A loses a dare.

Comment: "takes off ***her*** clothes"?  This agrees with the two "she"s later in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

[**Truth or dare**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_or_dare%3F) is a game where you are allowed to choose between either. If you choose dare, and for some reason you are not able to complete the given task in hand, they will force upon you to do something or the other. That's what happened with Rob. He lost, so his friends told him to get an embarrassing tattoo to go with.

However, I would like to highlight, it is not necessary for you to be drunk to play this game. It can be played anyhow. Sometimes it is played along with [**spin the bottle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_the_bottle) to choose who is to be asked/provided with the options.

The penalty upon loss is decided randomly (depending on your capability to do the job).